# compare list and get count

Tags: python, list

I have three lists

```
year= [2001, 2002, 2005, 2002, 2004, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2004, 2004 ]
indviduals= [12, 23, 24, 28,30, 15, 17, 18, 18, 19, 12, 15, 12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 15, 12, 12]
employers= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
```

when I run the script below, i can get the individual employees across the lists. What I want to do is

`a:[12, 15, 17, 15]` for year 2001

If I can do this I think the getting count is just length.

```
for index, item in enumerate(year): 
    for i in np.unique(employers[index]):
        count=0
        #print(i)

        #j=indviduals[index]
        count +=1
        print(i)
```

Comment: If you're using numpy, is there a reason you have three separate lists?

Comment: Not really. could be converted to array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing it for all your employers? using the buitin dict's method [`dict.fromkeys`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_fromkeys.asp)

```
d = dict.fromkeys(employers, ())
cond_year = 2001
for i,e,y in zip(indviduals, employers, year):
    if y == cond_year:
        d[e] = d[e] + (i,)
```

which prints

```
{'a': (12, 15, 17), 'b': (), 'c': (), 'd': (), 'e': ()}
```

Comment: kanak, where did you get that dict from? collections module?

Comment: @Ipt. Nop. Buit-in.

Comment: no that solution is wrong because it will include same exact 12, 15, 15 for every employer. thats wrong.

Comment: @Ipt You want them to be unique? I was not sure because of your example `a:[12, 15, 17, 15, ....]` that contains two `15`

Comment: yeah sorry. In current setting employers 'b', 'c', 'd', etc should not have individuals 12, 15, 17 for 2001. That could change in year 2002

Comment: @Ipt Are you sure of your second 15 ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use list comprehension

*Find all individuals whose matching element in the employers list is an "a"*

```
[individuals[i] for i, x in enumerate(employers) if x == 'a']
```

If you want to count it, then

```
sum(1 for x in employers if x == 'a')
```

Otherwise, I would suggest using a single list of tuples that you can more easily filter by and not store parallel lists

Comment: yes, but how do you condition that with 'year'? So basically for year 2001, employer a has these employees, employer b has these employee, etc

Comment: Add `and year[i] == 2001` to the conditional

Comment: And you can rewrite the same line for each employer string... If you actually want a group_by query, then that's where Pandas or a proper SQL database would help

Comment: yes sure, sql or pandas help, but trying to figure this out progamatically. I know this sounds weird but in bigger picture, I need to find out in multiple years which employee went to which employer. thats is something, i cannot find out in relational database, dynamically so to speak.

Comment: To be frank, I need to construct transition matrix out of this.

Comment: Your question seems to only be asking for the list of a values. I don't know what a transition matrix is, but I'm sure some database solution exists for it (for example, a graph database where each edge is a transition)

Comment: yep, you are totally right about the edges. its sort of like link (edge) formation. I have not used graph database but seems interesting